# Union of $l^p$ spaces for $p\in[1,q)$

Tags: functional-analysis

Inclusion of $l^p$ space for sequences has been discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/669360): for $1≤p<q≤\infty$, $l^p\subset l^q$.

then I have 2 questions in mind:

> Given $1<q<\infty$. Is it true that $\bigcup_{1 \leq p <q }l^p=l^q$?

and

> Given $1<p<\infty$. Is it true that $\bigcap_{p <q\le\infty }l^q=l^p$?

---

Inclusion of $L^p$ spaces for functions on $[0,1]$ has been discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66029): For $1≤p<q≤∞$, $L^q⊂L^p$.

similar questions:

> Given $1<q<\infty$. Is it true that $\bigcap_{1 \leq p <q }L^p=L^q$?

and

> Given $1<p<\infty$. Is it true that $\bigcup_{p <q\le\infty }L^q=L^p$?

Comment: What is $l^p$? As written, without more details, it's not true that $l^p \subset l^q$ if $p<q$

Comment: The inequality you speak of for $L^p$ is only true for finite measures and it's false, for instance, for $L^p(\Bbb R)$. Be as it may, for your questions it's Thatcher's answer: "No, no, no(, no)."

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Yes, I have added  "and finite measures"

Comment: For the second, consider $(n^{-1/p})_n$

Comment: For the others, I believe https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1243910/694754 should suffice.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio I changed $X$ to $[0,1]$. Thanks for the information